# reciever is not working when phone is restarted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, restart

I am using a Broadcast reciever to auto start my app whenever phone is switched on. But it is not working in my case. I am attaching the program details. Please somebody help me, where am I lagging behind. Thanks in advance

```
this is manifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vishal.readsimnumber">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".reciever.BootStartReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".FetchSimNumber"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>

this is my broadcast reciever

    public class BootStartReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BootStartReciever() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, FetchSimNumber.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);

        }
    }
}


this is my service class

public class FetchSimNumber extends Service {
    public FetchSimNumber() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(FetchSimNumber.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}

and this is my main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
        String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(getSimSerialNumber);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText(getSimNumber);


    }
}
```

Comment: put enable= true in your receiver.

Comment: hello sagar, you mean in manifest file

Comment: yes.. you can see my answer.

Comment: Does it work for restart also or only for power up.

Comment: Dude, it didn't work, just tell me will my app be open after starting up the phone

Comment: yep.. it work on both case..

Comment: that meant problem is in your broadcast receiver.. show me your broadcast receiver

Comment: no need to open your app for the start service, and make sure that your service is return START_STICKY.

Comment: public class BootStartReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BootStartReciever() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, FetchSimNumber.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);

        }
    }
}

Comment: can you do editing in my code, please.

Comment: ok.. i m checking now

Comment: if you are fetching phone numbers then your code is not completed..  but for now your code is allrights.. i cant find any error but i m sure you are missing something.

Comment: and yes, i will write whole code for fetching contact but not now.. i m little busy now,.

Comment: ok tell me how can I test that my reciever is working or not?

Comment: try to implemet this demo.. and you will understand everything about receiver and service,...      http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Comment: and this is for boot_complete...   http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html    and this one also,....    http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/12/android-autostart-app-after-boot-with.html#.V3oJQLh97Dc

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BootStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            /* Setting the service  here */
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Yourservice.class)
         context.startService(i);
}
```

and in your manifest file:

```
   <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
       android:enable="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

sometimes category.HOME not work so you can use category.DEFAULT also.. i dont know the reason behind this, but its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

> Receiver.xml

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

        **do your stuff at here...**

    }
}
```